# CPCL printing programming testing

Tags: printing, zpl

I'm trying to test code that sends a printing message to an iMZ320 printer. The printer takes instructions in the CPCL programming language. I don't have access to a printer I can print to, but I need to check some changes I have made to the printer code are formatting correctly. Is there any way to do that to test the code is displaying correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the answer is no.  Without access to the printer you cannot preview the changes.  Online tools like [Labelary](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) are only compatible with ZPL.  In practice, I find that even when I'm generating code from a WYSIWYG tool like Zdesigner, I always need to test and fine tune on an actual printer.